# Grammar of "with" in "We had no idea WITH what his purpose was"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

"I have no idea 'WITH' something". Is it correct to use *with* as a proposition here?
A line in a high school text book I saw says "We had no idea WITH what his purpose was"

Comment: It doesn't sound particularly grammatical, but could we have more context?

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe the sentence "We had no idea with what his purpose was," breaks any grammatical rules; however, it does not reflect modern style. The sentence sounds awkward. You may find it more elegant to omit the preposition *with* altogether.

Example:

"We had no idea what his purpose was."

This does not change the meaning of the sentence and reads more elegantly.

"I have no idea with something," could just as elegantly be shortened to "I have no idea."

I do not know if this fits with the context of the writing from which this sentence is extracted, but this edit is certainly more concise.